# 'MoneyField' object has no attribute 'serialize'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, saleor

I have model `Product` with field [`MoneyField`](https://github.com/mirumee/django-prices/blob/master/django_prices/models.py#L64) in `/products/models.py`

```py
class Product(SeoModel, ModelWithMetadata, PublishableModel):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    currency = models.CharField(
        max_length=settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY_CODE_LENGTH,
        default=settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY,
    )

    price_amount = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=settings.DEFAULT_MAX_DIGITS,
        decimal_places=settings.DEFAULT_DECIMAL_PLACES,
    )

    price = MoneyField(amount_field="price_amount", currency_field="currency")
```

My `views.py` is:

```py
from .models import Product
from .serializers import ProductListSerializer
from rest_framework import generics

class ProductList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductListSerializer
```

and `serializers.py`:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Product


class ProductListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'id']
```

and when i go to url i have error:

```
AttributeError at /ru/products/api/
'MoneyField' object has no attribute 'serialize'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ru/products/api/
Django Version: 2.2.6
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'MoneyField' object has no attribute 'serialize'
```

Can you help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

DRF's ModelSerializer assumes fields that are on the model extend `django.db.models.fields.Field`, which `MoneyField` does not. This is a problem when ModelSerializer is collecting fields:

```py
# rest_framework.utils.model_meta._get_fields
def _get_fields(opts):
    fields = OrderedDict()
    for field in [field for field in opts.fields if field.serialize and not field.remote_field]:
        fields[field.name] = field

    return fields
```

You can fix the problem by subclassing MoneyField:

```py
from django_prices.models import MoneyField as BaseMoneyField


class MoneyField(BaseMoneyField):
    serialize = True
```

This will probably lead to your next problem ;)

Comment: Did you change the Product model to use the changed MoneyField? (just making sure) and did you make a migration and migrated? Might be needed here.

Comment: Thank you. I add `serialize = True` in django_prices/models.py` to `class MoneyField` and its work. I did custom serializer:

```python
class ProductListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    price = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_price_from_product')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name', 'id', 'price')

    def get_price_from_product(self, product):
        return product.price_amount
```